# On_member_join, missing 2 required positional arguments: 'members' and 'member'

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make my bot message a new user, in bot api settings i have intents enabled and I have the members intent

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  await member.send('test')
```

and the error im getting is

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_member_join() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'members' and 'member'
```

I dont know what is going on

Comment: do you have the members intents enabled? If not, that would cause on_member_join() to fail

Comment: I don't think that's the code you're using.

Comment: Yes I have it enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your event for now, but you don't seem to have the intents enabled.

Head over to https://discord.com/developers/applications and look for your application.
Under the category `Bot` you find `Privileged Gateway Intents`. You can activate both.

In your code you then have to do the following:

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default() # Activate intents
intents.members = True # The intent you want
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-", intents=intents) # Import Intents

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('Welcome to the server.')
    print("Member joined.")
```

If you fulfill all these steps, the event should work.

Comment: I did try this, and yes I have the intents enabled in the bot application.
that is what i had before and it still didnt work, same error btw.

Comment: Do you have any other events with the name `on_member_join`? The code works fine for me so it must be something else.

Comment: OMG, thank you lol, Back then i must have had tried it - it didnt work so ig i might have gave up, but yea there was another on_member_join()

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to enable the intents

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()         # You need all to use the member join event, also activate them in the developers portal
client = commands.Bot(commands_prefix = '!', intents = intents)
```